# Introspection to look for what I'm missing

Tags: ethics, meaning-of-life, interpretation

I'm new in this area and I would like to ask some questions about introspection.

**About me**

I'm 22 years old. I'm bachelor in computer science. I live with my parents, I'm the only child, I work for an IT company (I started this year like a junior c# developer, full time, Monday to Friday 9am to 5pm), English language student, casual runner (two or three times weekly), casual reader (a few months ago I have started to read fiction books) and all the weekends I like to go to party. I could say that I have a normal life and a "good life".

**Personal Relationships**

Well, about my relation... I have a good relation with my mother, she understands me, she is an older lady (60 yo). The relation with my father is something turbulent, he is civil engineer and he pressures me a bit with the subject of studying. I don't have a girlfriend, i only have casual sex in the weekends but nothing more.

**Feelings**

I feel that despite everything I've achieved, I'm missing something but I don't know what, I don't feel full of life. I could say that I'm "asleep" but awake, loss of interest or something. So...

*The question is:* **How can I make an introspection?**

Suggestions or cases of life, everything is welcome, thanks for the area.

Regards.

Comment: The question seems very broad and perhaps only able to get opinions for answers.

Comment: Here is another edition of the journal Disputatio, https://archive.org/details/Disputatio2015 with some interesting articles. Have you ever studied film?  https://archive.org/details/A_Companion_to_Luis_Bunuel  Good luck on your journey!

Comment: "Como Leer un Libro" by Mortimer Adler. https://www.amazon.com/Como-Libro-Spanish-Mortimer-Adler/dp/9506200092  Here is a book on the generation of 1898, in English/Spanish. It begins with Miguel Unamuno. Very interesting. https://archive.org/details/deunamunoortegay00nava

Comment: Here are some philosophical articles, https://archive.org/details/Disputatio2014 Now regarding your father, he is merely jealous of your closeness to mama, so you have to find something in common with him, this book, perhaps:  https://archive.org/details/ConstruccionesDeHormignArmado

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I tried to ask the question as best I could, so it wouldn't be so general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing anything more about your life, I would agree with you that your life has many of the external features of "good life": you are busy, you are fit, you are productive, your relationships don't cause you drama.

In the terminology of Maslow, all the bricks in your pyramid hierarchy of needs are in place except for the ones at the very top.  What could fill that top place might be called "meaning".

I agree that *meaning* can be hard to find.  At work, meaning is obtained by satisfying the objectives of your boss.  At school, by satisfying the objectives of your teachers and the administration.  But without an authority on your personal life, this is a vacancy.

Authorities on your personal life can be formed in any way you wish.  For some, the urgency of preparing for a comfortable retirement feels like an authority on day-to-day decisions, or preparing for college education for children (requiring a lot of money to be saved-up).  For some it's environmental concerns, political concerns, the desire to accomplish athletic, artistic, or organizational things; the desire to travel, to collect, or to have the best home and car; learning, debating, or even trolling... this list goes on and on.

I think that the most worthwhile thing is to help other people.  Doing this is probably what more people call "rewarding" than any other thing you can do.

I hope that you find yourself thinking clearly and taking action decisively!

EDIT: I noticed that you said your father "pressures" you on studying.  Now that you are 22 years old, you may find it less meaningful to satisfy your father's intentions for you that when you were a child.

Or perhaps other things you do have cut off the possibility of satisfying your father as your personal authority; in my thinking, this would produce a vacancy in "meaning".

Answer (score 1):

While the question is broad, I think it is certainly asking about philosophy, even though it is not phrased directly.

From your question, it seems to me that you are asking "How can I find purpose in my life in order to feel motivated?"

Perhaps you should rephrase the question to ask: **What philosophers have written about the purpose of life or what man should to do during his life?**

Anyway, my suggestion is to find something that interests you, preferably something with a lot of depth that you can spend a lot of time learning about. This could be something like philosophy, literature, history, or music. It should be something that really teaches one about life (not something that is meant to 'entertain'). Personally, what made me "whole" and awakened me to the world was classical music.

Because I'm only starting out with philosophy, I don't really know of any specific books/philosophers who I found provided a good answer to your question. If you are interested in music however, I could certainly help you with that.

Simply Put:
***Find something to study or to do that you know is meaningful and teaches you about life and humanity.***

Comment: About music, I can play creole guitar and I also have a piano but I don't know how to play it.

Thanks you for your tip. i will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Christians of a certain tradition think that "meaning" is actually defined according to God.  In the "Shorter Westminster Catechism", the very first point (in Q&A form) is:

> What is the chief end of man?  The chief end of man is to glorify God and enjoy Him forever.

According to this thinking, anybody who isn't participating in the "chief end" of their own existence should probably notice that something is missing.